# The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize

Tags: tensorflow

I write a vae model which posterior is GMM ,and use self.add_loss to define vae loss,but an error occur when i fit my model:

**ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.**

here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np

tfd = tfp.distributions

tf.test.is_gpu_available()

# data
(x_train, x_labels), (x_val, x_val_labels) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255.
x_val = x_val.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255.
x_train[x_train >= 0.5] = 1.
x_train[x_train < 0.5] = 0.
x_val[x_val >= 0.5] = 1.
x_val[x_val < 0.5] = 0.


# from softmax to one_hot
def props_to_onehot(props):
    if isinstance(props, list):
        props = np.array(props)
    a = np.argmax(props, axis=1)
    b = np.zeros((len(a), props.shape[1]))
    b[np.arange(len(a)), a] = 1
    return b

# reparameter
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


class Encoder(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, latent_dim, base_depth, components, name='encoder', **kwargs):
        """
        latent_size: the dimensionality of latent variable z(also the dim of u and Σ)
        base_depth: base units of Dense
        components: the numbers of gussian distribution.In this case ,we set components = 10
        """
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.latent_size = latent_dim
        self.base_depth = base_depth
        self.components = components

        # shared structured of encoder
        self.dense1 = Dense(8 * self.base_depth, activation='relu', name='1')
        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.dense2 = Dense(4 * self.base_depth, activation='relu', name='2')
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.dense3 = Dense(4 * self.base_depth, activation='relu', name='3')
        self.dense4 = Dense(2 * self.base_depth, activation='relu', name='4')
        self.dense5 = Dense(2 * self.base_depth, activation='relu', name='5')
        # the output parameters of encoder including {pi,u,Σ}
        self.parameters = Dense(self.components + self.components * 2 * self.latent_size, name='6')
        self.sampling = Sampling()

    def call(self, inputs):
        # shared structure output
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.dense4(x)
        x = self.dense5(x)
        # meaningful parameters
        parameters = self.parameters(x)
        pi, _ = tf.split(parameters, [self.components, 10 * 2 * self.latent_size], axis=-1)

        pi = tf.nn.softmax(pi)
        pi = props_to_onehot(pi)
        batch_size_int = tf.shape(pi)[0].numpy()
        batch_list = []
        for i in range(batch_size_int):

            index = np.argmax(pi[0])

            batch_list.append(parameters[0][self.components + index * 2 * self.latent_size + 1:self.components + (
                    index + 1) * 2 * self.latent_size + 1])


        batch_list = np.array(batch_list)  # (batch_size,2*latent_size)
        # (batch_size,latent_size);(batch_size,latent_size)
        z_mean, z_log_var = tf.split(batch_list, [self.latent_size, self.latent_size], axis=-1)
        z = self.sampling((z_mean, z_log_var))
        kl_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)
        self.add_loss(kl_loss)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


class Decoder(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, base_depth, name="decoder", **kwargs):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

        self.base_depth = base_depth

        self.dense1 = Dense(self.base_depth)
        self.dense2 = Dense(2 * self.base_depth, activation='relu')
        self.dense3 = Dense(4 * self.base_depth, activation='relu')
        self.dropout1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.dense4 = Dense(4 * self.base_depth, activation='relu')
        self.dense5 = Dense(8 * self.base_depth, activation='relu')
        self.dropout2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        # no activation
        self.dense_out = Dense(784)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.dense4(x)
        x = self.dense5(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.dense_out(x)

        # shape=(B,784)
        return x


class GMM_VAE_Posterior(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, latent_dim, base_depth, components, name='auto_encoder', **kwargs):
        super(GMM_VAE_Posterior, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.base_depth = base_depth
        self.components = components

        self.encoder = Encoder(self.latent_dim, self.base_depth, self.components)
        self.decoder = Decoder(self.base_depth)

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        out = self.decoder(z)  # (batch_size,784)
        reconstructions_error = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=inputs, logits=out)
        reconstructions_error = tf.reduce_sum(reconstructions_error, axis=-1)
        reconstructions_error = tf.reduce_mean(reconstructions_error)
        self.add_loss(reconstructions_error)
        # shape:(batch_size,784)
        return out

vae_gmm = GMM_VAE_Posterior(16, 64, 10)
vae_gmm.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae_gmm.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64)  # error
```

In my view,i think the computation graph of my model is not complete,so model can not BP.But it is just my gusses.

Answer (score 0):

On model compiling, you *must* fill in the loss parameter. So, when you added the loss in another way, simply set it to None:

```
vae_gmm.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss = None)
```